# Save uploaded file Django Jquery Ajax

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am quite new in Python and Django and because im working on a big porject it's a bit difficult to see what I'm doing wrong.
I would like to save the uploaded File in my repository folder.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
            <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple="multiple" />
            <br /><br />
            <input id="upload_submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my views file, I dont really understand how the communication between the modules work here

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_text(self, request):
    rand_int = random.random()
    return JsonResponse({"text": "Random number: " + str(rand_int)}, status=200)

@csrf_exempt
def save_uploaded_file(self, request):
    rand_int = random.random()
    return JsonResponse({"text": "Random number: " + str(rand_int)}, status=200)
```

My urls look like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("save_uploaded_file/", url_Handler_Wrapper.save_uploaded_file, 
name="save_uploaded_file"),
    path("get_text/", url_Handler_Wrapper.get_text, name="get_text"),
    path("tasks/", url_Handler_Wrapper.run_task, name="run_task"),
    path("", url_Handler_Wrapper.home, name="home"),
]
```

And this is my javascript

```
$('#upload_submit').on('click', function() {

    var formData = new FormData(Document.querySelector('#myfile'))
    $.ajax({
       url: '/save_uploaded_file/',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: function (response) {
           if (response) {
               formData.write("/")
           }
       },
       error: function (error) {
           console.log(error)
       },
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Please mention  problem you're facing

Comment: I havent found a way to make the program save the uploaded file in my project repository. I would like to pass the file as an argument to the task save_uploaded_file. Thanks